# Entity Framework with Interface

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, interface

I know the normal programming. But now I would like to implement interfaces.

My question is if I have an MVC architecture what should an interface have only the controller or the models?

Why an interface? Since I should develop a controller for another company and they should be able to use the methods so empty.

If the models should also have an interface, how does the add with EntityFramework get this error:

```
public async Task<Result> CreateOrderingEquipmentAsync(IOrderingEquipment orderingEquipment)
    {
        var result = new Result();

        if (!ModelStateIsValid(orderingEquipment))
        {
            return BadRequest(orderingEquipment);
        }

        if (await GetOrderingEquipmentAsync(orderingEquipment.Guid) != null)
        {
            return AlreadyExist(orderingEquipment.Guid);
        }

        try
        {
            orderingEquipment.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
            _context.OrderingEquipments.Add(orderingEquipment);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            result = CreatedResult(orderingEquipment);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e);

            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Log.Error(e.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Omg, please make screenshot more readable and add referenced code

Comment: Don't include screenshots of your code - include the code itself. If you include images of something else, make sure to properly crop it.

Comment: I took a screenshot to display the error message

Comment: And you can zoom the Screenshot per click

Answer (score 0):

Your add method accepts an object of type OrderingEquipment but your variable is of type IOrderingEquipment.

Try casting it using the "as" keyword, then, after having checked for null, pass the newly created variable to your method.